# R: Manipulate values of one data frame column based on another column

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns

Let's say you have bank account information:

```
a=data.frame(Transaction=c(1,2,6,3,8,3,5.25,6.99,2,5),type=c("CREDIT","DEBIT","DEBIT","DEBIT","DEBIT","CREDIT","CREDIT","CREDIT","DEBIT","CREDIT"))
```

with rows including a dollar amount in the first column and whether it was taken or added to the account.  I want to manipulate the first row based on the second by keeping it positive if it's credit, but negating it if it's debit.  So far the best I've come up with is:

```
a$Transaction[a$type=="DEBIT"]=-a$Transaction
```

I am looking for a simple, non-loop solution, because I believe that such a solution exists in R.  Thanks, guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a[a$type=="DEBIT",]$Transaction <- -a[a$type=="DEBIT",]$Transaction
```

Is what you're looking for. You need commas to specify the fact that you're using the rows of the data frame.

Comment: That comma is what I had the most trouble with through all of my trial and error--thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

I prefer to do this in steps, and to create an index vector:

```
R> ind <- a[,"type"] == "CREDIT"
R> ind
 [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
R> a[ind, "Transaction"] <- - a[ind, "Transaction"]
R> a
   Transaction   type
1        -1.00 CREDIT
2         2.00  DEBIT
3         6.00  DEBIT
4         3.00  DEBIT
5         8.00  DEBIT
6        -3.00 CREDIT
7        -5.25 CREDIT
8        -6.99 CREDIT
9         2.00  DEBIT
10       -5.00 CREDIT
R>
```

Comment: Thanks for laying it out for me!